# Can't install pentaho business analytics 5.2.0.0-209-x64

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence

I tried to install Pentaho but I keep getting this error message: 
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
Error running sc config pentahobiservernum1 depend= "Pentaho Solution Repository-1" : Program ended with an error exit code.

After I close that one I also get :
Installation is unable to start Data Integration Server

Does anyone have a fix for this problem?

Comment: I assume there might be some issue while you were installing Pentaho mostly at the time of PDI server installation. Could you try reinstalling the Pentaho again ??

Comment: What OS? What java version? More details, please, too vague to be able to help.

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 at the moment with java 8. I also tried java 7 but that didn't matter. And I already tried to reinstall pentaho multiple times but that gave the same error messages.

Comment: I have faced same issues but i am not able to figure it out what was the issue

Comment: @user1485267 Please read my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this issue, I did exert a huge effort and finally could find the solution for this.

 If you have installed java make sure your environmental variable is `JRE_HOME` and not `JAVA_HOME`.

As per Oracle/Sun/JAVA:

 The `JAVA_HOME` Variable was designed to point to a JDK.  When Tomcat sees a `JAVA_HOME` it enables extra debugging.  In previous version of Tomcat  (6.0.39 and below), it would let you get away with having `JAVA_HOME` set to a JRE location.

The `JRE_HOME` Variable was designed to point to the JRE.  When Tomcat sees this ts does not enable the extra debugging.  The intention for this was for Production Server’s where you do not want that level of logging enabled.

Starting with Tomcat 6.0.40 (Pentaho 5.2 is shipped with 6.0.41) they have fixed this, and now require you to properly set the `JRE_HOME` or the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

**SUMMARY**: `JAVA_HOME` should be pointed to a jdk.  `JRE_HOME` should point to JRE.  New tomcat version won't allow the incorrect setting.
As an alternative way: Since Pentaho ships with Java you can uninstall all JRE and JDK and the related java variables and let Pentaho do it by itself

Comment: Its not summery, it is summary