# How do I install Pentaho 5.3 bi ce on Windows 2012 R2 *please*

Tags: java, installation, environment-variables, pentaho

Please do advise, have been stuck on this for quite some time.
Have tried downloading biserver-ce and downloaded JAVA SE jdk 8u45, edited environment variables as all the online sources have suggested (JAVA_HOME = dir of jdk file) (Path = \bin in dir of jdk)

Ran the pentaho-start.bat file but CMD output that Java_home variable was not correctly initialized, in debugging the set-pentaho-env.bat file showed that the message was being output due to a missing file -> jdb.exe, downloaded the file separately and the Tomcat terminal now opens but outputs many many errors, and visiting localhost 8080/pentaho does not work.

Please do advise on the correct installation steps, is it an issue with the environment variables?

Comment: Try this answer to correctly assign the variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755287/cant-install-pentaho-business-analytics-5-2-0-0-209-x64/29117192#29117192

Answer (score 0):

The conditions I got it to work are as follows:

Set environment Variables:

CATALINA_HOME to C:\biserver-ce\tomcat , 
JAVA_HOME to C:Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 , 
Path to C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin

The JDK version 7 was used.

Answer (score 0):

Yep Pentaho 5.3 won't work on Java 8, it needs Java 7.